# Showing that for a convergent sequence of elemenets of a set the limit of the sequence is a member of the set

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm confused as to how to prove this theorem, any tips would be helpful.

Comment: What is your definition of closed in this context?

Comment: Closed as in a set that contains all its limit points i think, i'm not 100% sure as the question is vague

Comment: And so, given a specific convergent sequence of the elements of $S$, is the sequence's limit a *limit point of $S$*?  Why?  What does your definition of closed then imply?

Comment: then obviously if a closed set contains all the limit points then it must contain the limit? I think i assumed there would be more to it